# Is there a better way to trigger ViewModel class sub object variable set property directly on VM

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Regarding data binding and updating on ViewModel.

I've created a `User` class which has Id, Email, Password.
On my XAML, I've used binding to a ViewModel which has a 'User' variable.
I've also created 2 individual properties on the ViewModel for Email and Password, and binded those directly into the Entry field.

In View Model. OnProperty change of Email/Password, I want to update User Property, but the OnPropertyChange doesn't get triggered in the ViewModel, but only on the User Class itself.

Is there a way to trigger the `OnPropertyChange` directly **on the ViewModel**? I've tried `OnPropertyChange(User).`

The only way I've figured how to do this is by creating a new instance of User with the newly set Email & Password parameter.
Is there a better way to this than creating a new User?

It doesn't work with Binding the User.Email in XAML either.

The thing is that User class gets triggered directly and triggers its' `set`, and **seems to bypass the LoginVM** User `set` property.

Login Button would remain disabled if not for the `RefreshUser()` function.

**Solution:** (I've re-edited my code to show the modification)
Ok I've done it. Managed to figure out the issue with the lack of updating. It was due to the Command being an ICommand and it lacked the `ChangeCanExecute` function. So I created an abstract class that generates the Command and includes a function to add the Command to the button.
Also thanks to @Jason for pointing me in the right direction of adding the property listener on the VM.

It may not be ideal, but it looks like the best solution I've found scouting the net. The closest I got was a RelayCommand. So I created my own replacement for the ICommand interface.

Suggestions are welcomed. Otherwise, hope this helps some out there.

BaseViewModel

```
public class BaseViewModel : ObservableObject
```

LoginVM

```
public class LoginVM : BaseViewModel {
public LoginCommand loginCommand { get; set; }

private Users user;
        public Users User
        {
            get => user;
            set => SetProperty(ref user, value);
        }

        private string email;
        public string Email
        {
            get => email;
            set => SetProperty(ref email, value, onChanged: ()=> { RefreshUser(); });
        }

        private string password;
        public string Password
        {
            get => password;
            set => SetProperty(ref password, value, onChanged: () => { RefreshUser(); });
        }

        private void RefreshUser()
        {
            User = new Users() { Email = this.Email, Password = this.Password };
        }

        public LoginVM()
        {
            User = new Users();
            loginCommand = new LoginCommand(this);
            regNav = new RegistrationPageNavigationCommand(this);

            //This was the main trigger
            User.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => {
                loginCommand.ChangeCanExecute();
            };
        }

        void ApplyCommand(Button button)
        {
            loginCommand.ApplyActionToButton(button);
        }
    ...
}
```

XAML Code:

```
    <Entry x:Name="emailEntry" Placeholder="Email Address"
            Text="{Binding Email, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Keyboard="Email">
    </Entry>
    <Entry x:Name="passwordEntry" Placeholder="Password"
            Text="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay}"
            IsPassword="True">
    </Entry>
    <Button x:Name="loginButton"
            Margin="0, 50, 0, 0"
            Text="Log In"
            Command="{Binding loginCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding User}"
            Style="{StaticResource normalButton}"
            />
```

LoginCommand

```
    public class LoginCommand : RedoneCommand
    {
        public LoginVM LoginVM { get; set; }

        public LoginCommand(INotifyPropertyChanged viewModel) : base(viewModel)
        {
            LoginVM = (LoginVM)viewModel;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            var user = (Users)parameter; //Passing through specifically this type.
            if (user == null) return false; //First launch - it checks and is null.
            string email = user.Email, password = user.Password;

            if (StringThings.IsValidEntry(email) && StringThings.IsValidEntry(password))
            {
                return true;
            }
                return false;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            LoginVM.Login();
        }
    }
```

Users

```
    [Table("Users")]
    public class Users : BaseViewModel
    {
        private string id;
        public string Id
        {
            get => id;
            set => SetProperty(ref id, value);
        }

        private string email;
        public string Email
        {
            get => email;
            set => SetProperty(ref email, value, onChanged: () => { });
        }

        private string password;
        public string Password
        {
            get => password;
            set => SetProperty(ref password, value, onChanged: () => { });
        }
```

RedoneCommand: (My ICommand Replacement)

```
namespace MVVM
{
    public abstract class RedoneCommand : ICommand
    {
        public INotifyPropertyChanged viewModel { get; set; }
        private Command command { get; set; }

        public RedoneCommand(INotifyPropertyChanged viewModel)
        {
            this.viewModel = viewModel;
            command = new Command(Execute, CanExecute);
            viewModel.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => { ChangeCanExecute(); };
        }

        public void ApplyActionToButton(Button button)
        {
            button.Command = command;
        }

        public void ChangeCanExecute()
        {
            command.ChangeCanExecute();
        }

        abstract public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
        abstract public bool CanExecute(object parameter);
        abstract public void Execute(object parameter);
    }
}
```

And on LoginVM:

```
        viewModel = new LoginVM();
        viewModel.ApplyCommand(loginButton);
        BindingContext = viewModel;
```

Comment: why do you need these two properties on the base VM and the User?  Why can't you just bind your `Entry` to `User.Email`?

Comment: Hi @Jason , thanks for getting back to me. I've tried this approach but it seems like the Binding from the Button to User doesn't seem to read the User property that it was updated.

If I had to put a break point on the above function it doesn't get called. Although a break point in the actual `Users->Email->set` gets triggered

It seems that the `public Users User` -> set .. Doesn't get triggered when an Entry gets changed.

Comment: changing a **property** of a class does not change the class itself

Comment: @Jason . I don't quite understand. 
If I changed the XAML for example:
```Text="{Binding User.Email, Mode=TwoWay}"```
The LoginVM Property for User doesn't get triggered as 'set'.

Comment: you are binding to the `Email` property of the `User` object, so only the `Email` setter is called.  The `User` object itself is not changed so it's setter is not called.  I really don't understand what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Ok, fair @Jason . I've updated the above sample to include the LoginCommand and the Users class.

Not sure what I'm missing then.
I just want the Users property to trigger the set on the LoginVM so that LoginCommand knows to update and hence the Button will be enabled. Otherwise only Email setter property is triggered and not the VMs User property.

Comment: have the VM assign an event handler to User's PropertyChanged event

Comment: @Jason Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Well, I've gotten the solution to work. I've edited all of the above. All the best and thanks :)
If there's anything to change or comment on, would be nice too.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my comment question with the solution at the bottom.
Needs a User.PropertyChanged and a Command.ChangeCanExecute() to update the UI.